# Implementing backpropagation for dataset preprocessing

Tags: backpropagation, data-preprocessing

I have this algorithm written that can perform the XOR operation. How can i modify it so that it can process the large dataset?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class MLP {

public static class MLPLayer {

float[] output,input,weights,dweights;

boolean isSigmoid = true;

public MLPLayer(int inputSize, int outputSize, Random r) {
output = new float[outputSize];
input = new float[inputSize + 1];
weights = new float[(1 + inputSize) * outputSize];
dweights = new float[weights.length];
initWeights(r);
}

public void setIsSigmoid(boolean isSigmoid) {
this.isSigmoid = isSigmoid;
}

public void initWeights(Random r) {
for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
weights[i] = (r.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * 4f;
}
}

public float[] run(float[] in) {
System.arraycopy(in, 0, input, 0, in.length);
input[input.length - 1] = 1;
int offs = 0;
Arrays.fill(output, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
 output[i] += weights[offs + j] * input[j];
}
if (isSigmoid) {
 output[i] = (float) (1 / (1 + Math.exp(-output[i])));
}
offs += input.length;
}
return Arrays.copyOf(output, output.length);
}

public float[] train(float[] error, float learningRate, float momentum) {
int offs = 0;
float[] nextError = new float[input.length];
for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
float d = error[i];
if (isSigmoid) {
d *= output[i] * (1 - output[i]);
}
for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
 int idx = offs + j;
 nextError[j] += weights[idx] * d;
 float dw = input[j] * d * learningRate;
 weights[idx] += dweights[idx] * momentum + dw;
 dweights[idx] = dw;
}
offs += input.length;
}
return nextError;
}
}
MLPLayer[] layers;

public MLP(int inputSize, int[] layersSize) {
layers = new MLPLayer[layersSize.length];
Random r = new Random(1234);
for (int i = 0; i < layersSize.length; i++) {
int inSize = i == 0 ? inputSize : layersSize[i - 1];
layers[i] = new MLPLayer(inSize, layersSize[i], r);
}
}

public MLPLayer getLayer(int idx) {
return layers[idx];
}

public float[] run(float[] input) {
float[] actIn = input;
for (int i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
actIn = layers[i].run(actIn);
}
return actIn;
}

public void train(float[] input, float[] targetOutput, float            learningRate, float momentum) {
float[] calcOut = run(input);
float[] error = new float[calcOut.length];
for (int i = 0; i < error.length; i++) {
  error[i] = targetOutput[i] - calcOut[i]; // negative error
}
for (int i = layers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
error = layers[i].train(error, learningRate, momentum);
}
}

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 float[][] train = new float[][]{new float[]{0, 0}, new float[]{0, 1},     new float[]{1, 0}, new float[]{1, 1}};
  float[][] res = new float[][]{new float[]{0}, new float[]{1}, new       float[]{1}, new float[]{0}};
  MLP mlp = new MLP(2, new int[]{2, 1});
  mlp.getLayer(1).setIsSigmoid(false);
  Random r = new Random();
  int en = 500;
  for (int e = 0; e < en; e++) {

  for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
  int idx = r.nextInt(res.length);
  mlp.train(train[idx], res[idx], 0.3f, 0.6f);
  }

  if ((e + 1) % 100 == 0) {
  System.out.println();
  for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
  float[] t = train[i];
  System.out.printf("%d epoch\n", e + 1);
  System.out.printf("%.1f, %.1f --> %.3f\n", t[0], t[1], mlp.run(t)[0]);
  }
  }
  }
  }
  }
```

How can i modify it for large number of inputs for the dataset? How can i know what output the dataset gives after processing of dataset? Would be grateful if someone helps me here.